# I am running Ubuntu 14.04, python 2.7.8, I try to install python-setuptools, but it is giving following message

Tags: 14.04, package-management, python, python-2.7

I am try to install python-setuptools but getting following messages: **You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: The following packages have unmet dependencies:**

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-setuptools is already the newest version.
python-setuptools set to manually installed.

You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 icedtea-7-jre-jamvm : Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u65-2.5.2-3~14.04) but 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.2 is to be installed
 openjdk-7-jre : Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u65-2.5.2-3~14.04) but 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
$ sudo easy-install virtualenv
sudo: easy-install: command not found
```

I also try to update (`sudo apt-get update`) but it is giving the same message.

Comment: So did you run `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: Thanks for replay, I did n't run this cmd. What it will do.

Comment: Your packages are in an inconsistent state. This command will try to make it consistent by adding or removing packages as necessary.

Comment: @muru, It is still giving the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Read this lines carefully

```
icedtea-7-jre-jamvm : Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u65-2.5.2-3~14.04) but 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.2 is to be installed
openjdk-7-jre : Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u65-2.5.2-3~14.04) but 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.2 is to be installed
```

All you need is reinstall `openjdk` package, because one of your packages depend on lower version of it.